How to tell if one player is significantly better at a multi-player game?
I've build a poker simulation and have let 6 bots play a lot of games against each other (randomly seated, always the same six), how would you determine whether one player is significantly better than the rest?
https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aay2400 uses a T-test, but I'm a bit confused by two things:
The need for independence... aren't the players highly dependent on the performance of the other players? So I would need to do a paired T-test right (wasn't stated in the paper)?
Let's say I want to compare the top two players. Would it just be a matter of comparing each of the players in a paired T-Test? I made an example for how this might look in Python:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

##### Seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

##### Number of games
n_games = 20

##### Create an empty DataFrame
data = {
    'game': range(1, n_games + 1),
    'good': [0] * n_games,
    'bad': [0] * n_games,
    'random_1': [0] * n_games,
    'random_2': [0] * n_games,
    'random_3': [0] * n_games,
    'random_4': [0] * n_games,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

##### Randomly choose one winner per game
winners = np.random.choice(['good', 'bad', 'random_1', 'random_2', 'random_3', 'random_4'], size=n_games)

##### Assign the winner for each game
for i in range(n_games):
    df.loc[i, winners[i]] = 1

##### Perform the paired t-test between "good" and "bad"
t_stat, p_value = stats.ttest_rel(df['good'], df['bad'])

##### Display the DataFrame and test results
print(df)
print(f"t-statistic: {t_stat}, p-value: {p_value}")

```

Tell me whether I have interpreted this correctly: it appears you measure performance solely in terms of win rates.  Consequently all the relevant information is contained in a contingency table giving the win counts for each of the six players.

It depends on how you will "score" winners and losers.
If you start each game, with each player having the same amount of \$ (or whatever currency you use), and end it when one player has won all the \$'s on the table (all the other players have lost everything), then you are looking at the counts of wins.
In this case, you have counts, and a t-test is not your best option (counts are never negative, are discrete, and are usually skewed positive). Not that a t test will be completely wrong, but there are more appropriate choices.
Your data will be a set of binomial counts (win/loss) for the 6 players. So you have a 6x2 contingency table, with counts of wins, and losses in the 2 rows. You can run a $\chi^2$ test, or a Fisher exact test (preferred if you have any cell count below 5; there are other "rules of thumb" for that, but this one is reasonable). Both tests will tell you if the distribution of wins/losses is the same for all 6 players, or not. If they are not the same, then you can use the player with your highest win count as "the best", and run 5 2x2 contingency tests (Fisher or $\chi^2$) comparing "the best" to the other 5, to see if this "best" player is significantly better. You may want to use a multiple comparison correction (MCC), maybe Bonferroni or Sidak? (they both give you a corrected $\alpha$=.01). The reason to only compare to "the best" is to reduce the number of comparisons (5, instead of 15). But in fact, you could just compare "the best" to the next best; if that is significant, then all other comparisons to the best will be significant; no need to correct $\alpha$. If not significant, then compare to the 3rd best, etc., until you find a significant results (at whatever your uncorrected $\alpha$ level is.
An alternative is to simply look at the # of wins, and compare them to the distribution where the each player won $\frac 1 6$ of the games (i.e. parity). Again run a $\chi^2$ or Fisher exact test; if significant, that will tell you that there is a "best player": the distribution of wins is not consistent with all players being equally good at poker. I suspect it will give you a very similar result. But then you still need to run 2x2 matrices to see which player is significantly better than which other player.
Now, you could also randomize the \$ amounts given to each player for each game. And maybe also stop after a given number $G$ of games (instead of when a winner takes all). There may be many other variations. In these cases you should look at the \$ amounts won by each player. Here, you could use a 1-way ANOVA (player being the factor, winnings being the dependent variable), and use a post-hoc test to see which player is different from which other player. Here too, I would use a comparison to the best (i.e. Hsu's Multiple Comparison to the Best -MCB-). ANOVA has some assumptions you would have to check.
